# show/ hide and reset angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

The page that I am developing does inspection. One location inspection has various programs. each programs has bunch of Q&A (multi select), textboxes and table(ngrepeat)

The problem i am facing is with Add of CRUD operation in table. My idea while coding was that I will have an Add button in a tr. When Add button is clicked another tr is made visible with ng-Show. The said tr will have text boxes & buttons(save and cancel). when save or cancel is clicked intended operation is conducted and the said row is made invisible

The problem is my hide does not work after saving nor does the textboxes clears

I have created a jsfiddle link to emulate the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/812/

my actual codecode

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" ng-disabled="IsReadOnlyView">
<thead>
    //headings
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="itemMS in item.MenuServedList" ng-form="FormEditMenu">
        //edit row
    </tr>
    <tr ng-hide="addModeMenu" ng-form="FormAddMenu">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="PortionSize" class="form-control input-sm" ng-required="true" name="PortionSize" ng-style="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.PortionSize.$invalid && { 'border' : 'solid 1px red' }" />
            <span ng-show="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.$dirty && FormAddMenu.PortionSize.$invalid" style="color:red;">Required</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="Items" class="form-control input-sm" ng-required="true" name="Items" ng-style="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.Items.$invalid && { 'border' : 'solid 1px red' }" />
            <span ng-show="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.$dirty && FormAddMenu.Items.$invalid" style="color:red;">Required</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="AmtPrepared" class="form-control input-sm" ng-required="true" numbers-only name="AmtPrepared" ng-style="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.AmtPrepared.$invalid && { 'border' : 'solid 1px red' }" maxlength="8" />
            <span ng-show="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.$dirty && FormAddMenu.AmtPrepared.$invalid" style="color:red;">Required</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="AmtServed" class="form-control input-sm" ng-required="true" numbers-only name="AmtServed" ng-style="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.AmtServed.$invalid && { 'border' : 'solid 1px red' }" maxlength="8" />
            <span ng-show="OnMenuSave && FormAddMenu.$dirty && FormAddMenu.AmtServed.$invalid" style="color:red;">Required</span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="AddMenuSave(FormAddMenu, PortionSize, Items, AmtPrepared, AmtServed, item); OnMenuSave = true; ">
                Save
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="CancelMenuAdd(FormAddMenu); addModeMenu = false; OnMenuSave = false;">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right" colspan="8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-show="addModeMenu" ng-click="addModeMenu = false; OnMenuSave = false;">
                Add
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
$scope.AddMenuSave = function (ngForm, PortionSize, Items, AmtPrepared, AmtServed, formDetail) {
    if (ngForm.$invalid) {
        ngForm.$dirty = true;
        var i = null;
        for (i in ngForm) {
            if (ngForm[i] && ngForm[i].hasOwnProperty && ngForm[i].hasOwnProperty('$dirty')) {
                ngForm[i].$dirty = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {

        var getData = ngReviewFormService.AddMenuSave(PortionSize, Items, AmtPrepared, AmtServed, formDetail.doc_id);
        getData.then(function (result) {
            formDetail.MenuServedList = result.data.menuList;
                $scope.PortionSize = $scope.Items = $scope.AmtPrepared = $scope.AmtServed = '';
                $scope.addModeMenu = true;
        }, function (error) {
            OpenModal("Error occurred! Please contact system administrator");
        });
    }
};


$scope.CancelMenuAdd = function (ngForm) {
    ngForm.$setPristine();
    ngForm.$setUntouched();
    $scope.PortionSize = $scope.Items = $scope.AmtPrepared = $scope.AmtServed = '';
}
```

Comment: So, I've fixed your fiddle to do what you expect in your `Save` method. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/823/)

Comment: Also, if you need a deeper explanation on what I did I recommend you to read this article: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: @LuizCarlos Thanks